# about one function that splits a string with several chars in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

this is a function I found on the internet, but I'm not sure what does the line `s,res = res,[]` mean, can anyone explain this to me? Thank you very much!

```
def my_split(s, seps):
    res = [s]
    for sep in seps:
        s, res = res, []
        for seq in s:
            res += seq.split(sep)
            return res
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s, res = res, []
```

Means

```
s = res
res = []
```

Replacement of variable in single line.